# Node.JS verify Google Authentication token

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, access-token, google-authentication

I am trying to build a Node.JS REST server using the Express.JS framework that integrates Google authentication for mobile applications. The Node.JS version used is 0.12.7.

I am having a problem when verifying the Google token received from the application, as it seems that the module I am trying to load returns an error.

The module used to verify this token is [passport-google-token](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google-token). The code used to initialize this module and check the token is as follows:

index.js file

```
'use strict';

import express from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
import {setTokenCookie} from '../../auth.service';

var router = express.Router();

router
  .post('/callback', passport.authenticate('google-token'), setTokenCookie);

export default router;
```

passport.js file

```
import passport from 'passport';
import GoogleTokenStrategy from 'passport-google-token';

export function setup(User, config) {
  passport.use(new GoogleTokenStrategy({
    clientID: config.google.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.google.clientSecret
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOne({'google.id': profile.id}).exec()
      .then(user => {
        if (user) {
          console.log(user);
          return done(null, user);
        }

        user = new User({
          name: profile.displayName,
          email: profile.emails[0].value,
          role: 'user',
          username: profile.emails[0].value.split('@')[0],
          provider: 'google',
          google: profile._json
        });
        console.log(user);
        user.save()
          .then(user => done(null, user))
          .catch(err => done(err));
      })
      .catch(err => done(err));
  }));
}
```

When I try to start the server I am receiving the following error:

```
D:\Work\SoftwareUp\softwareup_android_demo\server\server\auth\google\mobile\passport.js:19
  _passport2.default.use(new _passportGoogleToken2.default({
                         ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.setup (D:/Work/SoftwareUp/softwareup_android_demo/server/server/auth/google/mobile/passport.js:5:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:/Work/SoftwareUp/softwareup_android_demo/server/server/auth/index.js:13:37)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at loader (D:\Work\SoftwareUp\softwareup_android_demo\server\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\Work\SoftwareUp\softwareup_android_demo\server\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.exports.default (D:/Work/SoftwareUp/softwareup_android_demo/server/server/routes.js:15:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:/Work/SoftwareUp/softwareup_android_demo/server/server/app.js:27:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at loader (D:\Work\SoftwareUp\softwareup_android_demo\server\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\Work\SoftwareUp\softwareup_android_demo\server\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Work\SoftwareUp\softwareup_android_demo\server\server\index.js:12:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
Stopping Express server
```

From what I have figured there is a problem when calling the constructor but I am not sure what that problem is.

Could you please help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to change your import code from

`import GoogleTokenStrategy from 'passport-google-token';`

to

`import { Strategy as GoogleTokenStrategy } from 'passport-google-token';`

Comment: Thank you, This has solved my problem and it seems to work now.